# Kivy: Don't make the UI unresponsive with long tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have created a little app with kivy, and user need to register on a website. To do that, I use Selenium Driver: I open website and wait to the user register. Then, I collect a link (using Selenium). The problem is that it makes the UI unresponsive. And I need to collect the link, so I can't use Thread (or I don't know how to do it).

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions as sel_exceptions

KV = """
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        on_press: app.open_webbrowser("http://google.com", "path/to/chrome_webdriver.exe")
        text: "open web browser"
"""
# Chrome web driver can be download here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

class MainApp(App):  
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def open_webbrowser(self, url, webdriver_path):
        with webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_path, service_args=["hide_console"]) as driver:
            driver.get(url)
            default_window = driver.current_window_handle
            while True:
                if driver.current_url != url:
                    if "goal_url.com" in driver.current_url:
                        validate_url = driver.current_url
                        driver.quit()
                        return validate_url
                    elif len(driver.window_handles) != 1:
                        for window in driver.window_handles:
                            if window != default_window:
                                driver.switch_to.window(window)
                                driver.close()
                        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Anyone have an idea how can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the web driver in another thread like this:

```
import threading

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions as sel_exceptions

KV = """
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        on_press: app.start_webdriver_thread("http://google.com", "path/to/chrome_webdriver.exe")
        text: "open web browser"

"""
# Chrome web driver can be download here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def start_webdriver_thread(self, url, webdriver_path):
        threading.Thread(target=self.open_webbrowser, args=(url, webdriver_path), daemon=True).start()

    def open_webbrowser(self, url, webdriver_path):
        with webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_path, service_args=["hide_console"]) as driver:
            driver.get(url)
            default_window = driver.current_window_handle
            while True:
                if driver.current_url != url:
                    if "goal_url.com" in driver.current_url:
                        validate_url = driver.current_url
                        driver.quit()
                        return validate_url
                    elif len(driver.window_handles) != 1:
                        for window in driver.window_handles:
                            if window != default_window:
                                driver.switch_to.window(window)
                                driver.close()
                        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! But like that, how can I collect and return the link? If I use something like returned_value = threading.Thread(target=self.open_webbrowser, args=(url, webdriver_path), daemon=True).start() It'll wait for the end of the Tread and block the UI anyway

Comment: From within `open_webbrowser()` you can do anything that you can do in any other method, with the exception of anything that modifies the GUI. And if you want to modify the GUI, call a method that does the modification via `Clock.schedule_once()`. So, if you have a method that you want to run (within the above restriction), you can just call it.